# C# catch kill command

Tags: windows, kill

how can I catch windows taskkill command in order to prevent it?

Comment: For what purpose? It sounds like you might be building something that I would not like to have on my computer, so you should give some background if you want people to help you.

Comment: It's quite a bad habit to always think the worst.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You **cannot** prevent your process being killed. The only way to keep a program alive is to have a second **Watchdog** application that is constantly pooling that process to ensure it's running.

So, you have two Applications; AppA (Main) and AppB (Watchdog).

> `AppA` checks if `AppB` is running. If
>   not, `AppA` starts `AppB`.
>
> `AppB` checks if `AppA` is running. If
>   not, `AppB` starts `AppA`.

But this is usually a design for a *malicious* process, so I hope you're not doing anything untoward.

You can see the following events in the message queue when **End process** is clicked:

> WM_CLOSE // UI app
>
> CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT //
>   Console app

But if your application does not close in a timely manner, then the kill command will be sent, which cannot be captured.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure it is not possible, otherwise a single application could stop windows from ever shutting down.  Even when the process is hung, killing it in task manager eventually works.  If it was possible, malicous software, etc would probably have a hey-day using it - not only could they take control of various parts of your PC, they'd make sure you could never get it back again.